# Impero - when does it work?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, process

I have a question about Impero. Does it work when I'm not connected to my school's Wi-Fi? The process "ImperoGuardianSVC" is working all time in background.

*Impero is a school program to prevent doing something others than School things*

Comment: I would guess that `ImperoGuardianSVC` looks for a Impero server on the network. If there isn't one available it knows you are not in school. A tool like WireShark might be able to capture the traffic and see the address it looks for.

Comment: I should caution you that disabling this software may result in serious consequences. If in doubt ask your system admin.

Answer (score 0):

Did they make you guys install something on your phone/laptops ? If not then it cannot really prevent anything beyond school network.

Even if they did, I doubt it will be set to work beyond their network.

Comment: They installed it on laptops

Answer (score -1):

It will log in the background, and the logs made available to your administrator when you return to school. I know this because we use it to, amongst other things, shut down computers at the end of the school day, and the first time we used this it turned off all the teachers laptops at home.